# i want to collapse my menu one by one not like collapse at a time and the menu which collapsed then i want to see it in more menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to collapse the menus one by one.

Here's an example: https://www.bbc.com/urdu (See the menu at different screen size)

Here's my code:

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color:white;
}
a:hover{
  color:black;
}
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}
body{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
header{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  width:100%;
}
.logo_section{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding:20px 15px;

}
.menu_section{
  background:#970000;
  padding:15px 0px;
  width:100%;
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
}
.menu_section ul{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.menu_section a{
  margin-right:5px;
  padding:15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
     <header>
         <div class="logo_section">
           <div class="domain_logo">
             <h2>knowledgecenteronline.com</h2>
           </div>
           <div class="site_description">
             <h3>Enter To Learn Leave To Serve</h3>
           </div>
         </div>
    </header>
         <div class="menu_section">
           <ul>
             <li><a href="html.html">HTML</a></li>
             <li><a href="css.html">CSS</a></li>
             <li><a href="javascript.html">JAVASCRIPT</a></li>
             <li><a href="sql.html">SQL</a></li>
             <li><a href="python.html">PYTHON</a></li>
             <li><a href="php.html">PHP</a></li>
             <li><a href="bootstrap.html">BOOTSTRAP</a></li>
             <li><a href="jquery.html">JQUERY</a></li>
             <li><a href="node.html">NODE.JS</a></li>
             <li><a href="ajax.html">AJAX</a></li>
             <li><a href="jason.html">JASON</a></li>
             <li><a href="angular.html">ANGULARJS</a></li>
           </ul>
         </div>
```

Comment: Please add some interpunction in your question. Right now it is hard to read. And please provide an example of the desired result.

Comment: https://www.bbc.com/urdu   check this site when the size is decreased then see the menu where it goes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the developer tools "inspect element" of your sample website. The last/ first links are classed and styled differently allowing the stacking behaviour you saw